# Local host 5000 "cannot GET / " firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to run a tictactoe game using firebase. I have initialized my file and on the console it says everything is running, except when I open localhost:5000 it gives me error Cannot GET/.  on the firebase CLI console it gives me error code:
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023:17:20:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "http://127.0.0.1:4001/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIxiF.png)

[firebase.json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM906.png)

I have tried rebooting my computer and changing around my code to some answers I have read on here, Its just not working.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen other than the 404? It sounds like you don't have any hosting content files to serve. We can't see everything you've placed locally, so we don't know what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Also I will point out that the output says you have multiple emulators running at the same time, which shouldn't happen if you rebooted and then tried to run the emulator first thing.